# Tweepy , error al filtrar una palabra

Tags: python, tweepy

El tema es que estoy cogiendo tweets , pero entre ellos quiero filtrar por ejemplo los que contengan la palabra "bueno" , pero en ningún momento me pasa el filtro , y me devuelve todos los tweets ignorando el filtro , he probado con track

```
search_words=[]
date_since = "2018-11-16"
tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                       q=search_words,
                       lang="es",
                       tweet_mode="extended",
                       track=["bueno"], ####AQUI ###
                       since=date_since).items(50)


# Collect a list of tweets
tw = [tweet.full_text for tweet in tweets]

print(tw)
for x in tw:
   print(x)
```

Y también he probado:

```
tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                       q=search_words,
                       lang="es",
                       tweet_mode="extended",                       
                      since=date_since).items(50)



# Collect a list of tweets
tw = [tweet.full_text for tweet in tweets]

print(tw)
for x in tw:
  if "bueno" in x: ###AQUI###
     print(x)
```

¿Alguna idea que puede estar pasando? ¿Quizás sea algo de parsear antes las frases de como vienen en twitter?